# Rearrange the words to make meaningful sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

I have a hard time rearranging these words (kind of sentence to be made is indicated in the brackets):

1) Magnanimous her how our all ignore of to weaknesses (Exclamatory)

2) to the agent did plan tour the itinerary satisfaction your (Interrogative)

Comment: You might tell us what you understand by exclamatory and interrogative. We really cannot do your homework for you. You might want to visit the Help section to see which questions are allowed. https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: It is questionable whether this type of question is in scope or not. Regardless, please provide details about the source of the content in your text (are these exam questions? homework? What level of English is it for?)

Comment: @Lambie Sorry to say this but what's the point in telling what are "Exclamatory and Interrogative sentences". It's like if i am asking about some math equation......i have to first define, what's variable, what's a coefficient, what's '=' sign ..... Seriously ?

Comment: @laugh Thanks for pointing it out, i'll provide source of the problems from now on. By the way, I'm teaching myself 'English' .......out of 15 questions, i did 13 myself. These two are somewhat difficult for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sentence, it should be "how", not "now".

> How magnanimous of her to ignore all our weaknesses!

"itinerary" is always a noun, and it usually goes with "to plan". It's planned by a person ("agent") who organises tours ("tour agent"). It's past time because of "did". "agent" is a subject.

> Did the tour agent plan the itinerary to your satisfaction?